Background color changing based on value
It's my Post component. When I add post title must have different background color based on what I Selected. I tried so many things but my brain not working.
const TaskM = () => {
const { myapp,handleRemoveTodo,desc,handleAddTodo } = useContext(Context);

let bgColor ='';

switch (desc) {
    case 'Banner':
        bgColor = 'bg-red-500'
        break;
    
    case 'Illustration':
        bgColor='bg-yellow-500'
        break;

    case 'Video':
        bgColor ='bg-blue-500'
        break;
    case 'UI UX':
        bgColor= 'bg-cyan-500'
}

return (
    <div className='flex flex-col  '>
        <ul className="todo-list">
            {(myapp || [])?.map((blog: any, index: number) => 
                    return <>
                        <div className='bg-white rounded-2xl flex '>
                            <div className='flex flex-row mt-2 justify-between w-[90%] '>
                                <h1 className='text-black w-[90%] '>
                                    <li className=' text-gray-700 md:break-words w-[90%] mb-3 flex flex-row text-xs justify-between items-center rounded-lg' id={blog.title} key={index}>
                                        {blog.title}
                                        {/* {JSON.stringify(_cards)} */}
                                    </li>
                                </h1>
                                <button " onClick={() => handleRemoveTodo(index)}>
                                    <BsThreeDots />
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div className='w-full'>
                            <li className={`${bgColor}`} id={blog.desc} key={index}>
                                {blog.desc}
                            </li>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>

                    </>;
                

            }

            )}

        </ul>
    </div>
)

}
here is my Select and options
<Modal show={openModal} onClose={onCloseModal} size="md" popup>
                        <div className="space-y-6">
                            <div className="text-xl font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">
                            
                            </div>
                            <div className="max-w-md">
                                <div className="mb-2 block">
                                    <Label htmlFor="countries" value="Select your country" />
                                </div>
                                <Select
                                    id="countries"
                                    required
                                    onChange={(e) => setTask(e.target.value)}
                                >
                                    <option >Banner</option>
                                    <option >Illustration</option>
                                    <option >Video</option>
                                    <option >UI UX</option>
                                </Select>
                            </div>
                            


                            <form method="dialog" className='flex flex-row  gap-2'>
                                <button 
                                    onClick={() => {
                                        setOpenModal(false)
                                        handleAddTodo()
                                    }}>Add</button>
                                <button onClick={onCloseModal}>Close</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                </Modal>

Im beginner and I don't know what am I doing wrong. Im using Nextjs and tailwind for styling. please help im stuck :( Sry for bad English.

hope this would be helpful,

At TaskM, you should remove return or missing a { inside map function since you're using arrow function.
Your desc is coming from useContext, I assume it's a state defined by useState, cause your select behavior did not update desc state, therefore UI won't be updated.
Try extract setDesc or your desc setter function from useContext, and replace useTask of onChange event handler in Modal.


oh I mixed desc " description " as task "title". after I fixed it it still not working as I thought. It changing every post color into same when I choose different titles. And 1. is my mistake while I was copying my code into here.

If the UI can be updated based on desc, then might be your styling issue, have you styled  into display:block?
